# Executing a function after 1 min if buttons stays untouched in Arduino Uno

Tags: timer, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm doing a calculator with Arduino Uno. I'm using a 4x4 keypad, and 16x2 LCD for display. Here's my question: If the buttons on keypad stays untouched for 1 min, the program will execute a function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `millis()` to measure the time and a simple flag `boolean` with `digitalRead()` to determine wheter a pushed button is released. It should be something like that (not tested yet):

```cpp
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 60000;
int buttonPin = 4;
boolean buttonReleased=false;

void setup(){
}

void loop(){
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  // edit, thanks to frarugi87
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW){
    buttonReleased = true; 
    previousMillis = currentMillis; 
  } 

  if((currentMillis - previousMillis > interval)&&buttonReleased ) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;  
    buttonReleased =false;
    // execute a function
  }
}
```

EDIT: Correct the keypad condition.

Comment: in keypad's buttons its not HIGH or LOW, I edited the code a little bit but no its not working.

Comment: The `currentMillis - previousMillis > interval` part is a very established code snippet for Arduino and should work. You could test it separately with a lower interval (for example `interval=1000;`). How you trigger the code depends on your keypad code. I was assuming that you use simple tactile push-buttons or similar hardware, that you can adapt to the code example above.

Comment: This can't work. The proper code is `if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW)
  {
    buttonReleased = true;
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }` because you have to reset `previousMillis` every time the button is pressed. `buttonReleased` now should be called `executeFunction` or something like that, because is just used to avoid firing the function twice.